# Eclipse- Strange AVD behaviour

Tags: android, eclipse

I am just learning to program Android apps with Eclipse and I am trying to run the "hello world" default app on an AVD.

But upon launching the AVD it shows a fancy "ANDROID" title for a few minutes, then shows "Just a minute..." for a few more minutes, then says it doesn't have a wifi connection. This entire time I find myself unable to actually run the application by clicking run.

I am very new to this so there is probably something extremely simple I'm missing.

Comment: Now that you have explained what you have seen, what is your actual question? If you saw the Android load screen from the Emulator chances are you successfully ran the application. And if you want a hello world app, just create a new project and without doing anything, run the application. Generally if you create an application in Eclipse with Activities, it is a hello world project.

Comment: AVD takes an age to load up and can run like a dog - this is just the way things are. You also should not close the emulator between runs. BTW, you might find that using a real Android phone is more efficient for development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the Android emulator so slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow)